# Fragment: getActivity() is null after onPause()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have several Fragments that are hosted by an activity. They register listeners that are called from a custom Application class in `onResume()` and unregister them in `onPause()`.
The Activity sometimes exchanges Fragments by using `fragmentTransition.replace(...)`

Sometimes (quite rare) `getActivity()` that is called in the listeners returns null.
How is that possible? The listener should not be called because he should unregister first?

To force this, you can install [my app](https://github.com/Ph1b/MaterialAudiobookPlayer/releases/download/v2.0.6/map-v2.0.6.apk) and click on a cover (calls replace on a new fragment) and turn the device (runtime change) at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, but can you please explain if this is so obvious?

Comment: Where do you get the NPE? Title mentions `onStop()`, text says `onPause()`. In which context is the fragment used? E.g. fragments in `ViewPagers` may have a `null` activity when they are not visible on screen. Downvote is probably because you are providing too little information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Regarding your question: It's probably because of a ViewPager. But we don't really know, that's why it's important to post the error log and more information about your implementation. The nature of Android are messages (intents) that are processed by an asynchronous queue. So if you have a timing problem, you should tell as much as possible about the context your error occurrs in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the contribution. I fixed this issue. It was caused by a very rare race condition. I locked the accessors correctly, but assumed something wrong, when I used a handler to post to the ui thread. This had a very tiny delay that caused the race condition to fail.

I fixed it by using getActivity().runOnUiThread(...) instead which has no delay.
Sorry for bothering with this very specific problem.